# Code in the workbook module still runs after the file is saved as xlsx

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, events, office-interop

Using a button in VB.NET form, an `.xlsm` file is opened and saved as `.xlsx`. The code in the `.xlsx` file (`Workbook_BeforeClose` event) is NOT deleted after the file is saved, therefore, when I want to close the file the code runs! After reopening the file there is no code left.

This is my VB.NET class:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkbooks As Excel.Workbooks

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks
        xlWorkBook = xlWorkbooks.Open("C:\Temp\testTemplate.xlsm")

        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\Temp\testTemp.xlsx", FileFormat:=51)  '51=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

        xlApp.Visible = True

        'Clean Up
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkbooks)
        releaseObject(xlApp)
    End Sub

    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is in the Excel file, workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "event still runs"
End Sub
```

How to save the file properly so that NO code would remain in it?

Comment: You're right, the code isn't deleted until after it's closed. I suppose you could set some type of flag in the xlsm's BeforeClose event that checks its file type and only runs if it's xlsm. Or you could do a `Worksheets.Copy` instead of the `SaveAs` and save the resulting workbook (which won't contain the VBA) as an xlsx, but there could be reference issues to clean up. Or you could set `xlApp.EnableEvents=False`, close the newly saved xlsx, set it back to `True` and re-open the xlsx.

Comment: I don't like the first option, as users will work with that file, and I don't want them to even have the code in the file (I'm too paranoid). I wonder which of your second 2 options would be faster. I suppose it should be `Worksheets.Copy`. Maybe you could expand on reference cleaning up issues?

Comment: You might not have any issues. Here's a post I wrote about this process: http://yoursumbuddy.com/copy-an-xlsm-xlsx/

Comment: To clarify, the first one was only for that one time that you're closing it while it's an xlsx. I may not understand the sequence of events correctly, but the idea was just to keep the BeforeClose from running that one time after you save it. This doesn't seem to affect future users.

Comment: That one time is actually the only time when a user would use the file :) Next time a new file is generated. I'm reading the article that you referenced. I think I'll try implementing the `Worksheets.Copy` option.

Comment: This is a bit of a kludge, but you could set `xlApp.EnableEvents=False`, close the workbook, enable events,  and then re-open it since it appears that you want to leave the workbook open.  Edit:  you can use `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook` for the file format instead of 51.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the code isn't deleted until after it's closed. I suppose you could set some type of flag in the xlsm's `BeforeClose` event that checks its file type and only runs if it's xlsm. Or you could do a `Worksheets.Copy` instead of the `SaveAs` and save the resulting workbook (which won't contain the VBA) as an xlsx, but there could be reference issues to clean up. Or you could set `xlApp.EnableEvents=False`, close the newly saved xlsx, set it back to True and re-open the xlsx.

Here's a post I wrote on the second option: http://yoursumbuddy.com/copy-an-xlsm-xlsx/

Comment: I chose the second option. In this case users will have no chance to be exposed to the code in workbook module. Also, it looks like it's faster performance-wise than your third option.

Comment: I agree with both those things. Glad it worked for you.